# Asp.Net MVC - redirect to same page without passing parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to redirect in same Index page that do multiple actions.

The problem is when in Index page with id parameter "http://example.com/Student/Index/1"
Url.Action("Index") or Html.ActionLink("Index") will always generate : "http://example.com/Student/Index/1" instead of "http://example.com/Student"

This happen on Menu and Breadcrumb.

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
   if (id == null) {
      // Show List
   } else if (id <= 0) {
      // Show Create Form
   } else {
      //Show Edit Form
   }
}
```

Is there any way to redirect to same page without parameter on View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the route value to an empty string

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "Index", new { id = "" })
```

Comment: Wonderful, I never though int could accept something like this. Its working, Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

There can be multiple ways.
Action Link which generates the html link

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

generate as :

```
<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>
```

URL.action which only genrates url which you will need to put in html link tag

```
Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })
```

generates

```
/somecontroller/someaction/123
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? I suggest you read it again carefully.